# What Am I?...If you throw me out the window

Tags: riddle

```
If you throw me out the window,  
I'll leave a grieving wife.  
Bring me back, but through the door,  
You'll see someone giving life.
```

What am I?

Quite old apparently but it took me awhile to figure out.

Comment: in answer to the title: defenestrated

Comment: no, the answer to the title is: OUTSIDE!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The answer is the Letter "N" Window = Widow Door = Donor

Comment: Aww solved so fast. Have you heard it before?

Comment: I remembered it from old times and had to think just a few seconds till i remembered it :P

Comment: But when i solved it for the first time it nearly cracked my head :D